# A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://facebook.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute

Tags: javascript, html

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Spy.png)
My website has a warning error as shown. How to solve it?[sim phong thuy](https://simkinhdich.com/)